# d3js - adding a parent element to a selection

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How can i add with d3.js a parent element to a selection. Lets say I have the following

```
<div class="i need a parent">...</div>
<div class="i need a parent">...</div>
```

and i want to modify this into

```
<a href="...">
    <div class="i need a parent">...</div>
</a>
<a href="...">
    <div class="i need a parent">...</div>
</a>
```

Any suggestion highly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like D3 wouldn't be the right tool for this. What you need to do is add the parent elements, detach the children from the DOM and reattach them to the parents.

Comment: Thanks Lars. i was afraid that that is the answer but was hoping magic d3.js has something to offer - thanks once more for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible purely with d3, but easy enough with a little standard JavaScript

```
var selection = d3.selectAll('div.needparent');
selection.each(function() {
    var oldParent = this.parentNode;
    var newParent = document.createElement('a');
    oldParent.replaceChild(newParent, this);
    newParent.appendChild(this);
})
```

You can use d3 for some of the operations within the iteration, but since `replaceChild` requires standard JavaScript I stuck with that throughout.

One note of caution, if you have event handlers bound to the child elements, I'm not sure they'll be preserved with this approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot Stephen, i was not aware of replaceChild which does the trick.

Comment: Ironically this doesn't seem to work on SVGs. Only HTML.